# PyAudio not capturing correct audio data

Tags: python, ubuntu, audio, alsa, pyaudio

I can't get a PyAudio stream to capture audio data from my USB microphone.

I'm running a Python program on Ubuntu trusty (Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS). I've configured ALSA to set my USB microphone as the default sound card, and tested that this work's properly by running:

`arecord -D plughw:0,0 -f cd test.wav`

and then playing that audio back using

`aplay -D plughw:0,0 test.wav`

**My `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` file looks like this:**

```
# autoloader aliases
install sound-slot-0 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-0
install sound-slot-1 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-1
install sound-slot-2 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-2
install sound-slot-3 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-3
install sound-slot-4 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-4
install sound-slot-5 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-5
install sound-slot-6 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-6
install sound-slot-7 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-7

# Cause optional modules to be loaded above generic modules
install snd /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-ioctl32 ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; }
#
# Workaround at bug #499695 (reverted in Ubuntu see LP #319505)
install snd-pcm /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-pcm $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-pcm-oss ; : ; }
install snd-mixer /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-mixer $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-mixer-oss ; : ; }
install snd-seq /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-seq $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-midi ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-oss ; : ; }
#
install snd-rawmidi /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-rawmidi $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-midi ; : ; }
# Cause optional modules to be loaded above sound card driver modules
install snd-emu10k1 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-emu10k1 $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-emu10k1-synth ; }
install snd-via82xx /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-via82xx $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; }

# Load saa7134-alsa instead of saa7134 (which gets dragged in by it anyway)
install saa7134 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install saa7134 $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist saa7134-alsa ; : ; }
# Prevent abnormal drivers from grabbing index 0
options bt87x index=-2
options cx88_alsa index=-2
options saa7134-alsa index=-2
options snd-atiixp-modem index=-2
options snd-intel8x0m index=-2
options snd-via82xx-modem index=-2
# options snd-usb-audio index=-2
options snd-usb-audio index=0
options snd-usb-caiaq index=-2
options snd-usb-ua101 index=-2
options snd-usb-us122l index=-2
options snd-usb-usx2y index=-2
# Ubuntu #62691, enable MPU for snd-cmipci
options snd-cmipci mpu_port=0x330 fm_port=0x388
# Keep snd-pcsp from being loaded as first soundcard
options snd-pcsp index=-2
```

I've installed PyAudio successfully, however when I open a stream, I don't get any audio data. My understanding is that the default device is used when opening a stream with PyAudio (unless otherwise specified by the `input_device_index` argument which I am not setting).

```
    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    stream = p.open(
        format=pyaudio.paInt16,
        channels=1,
        rate=18000,
        input=True,
        frames_per_buffer=1024
    )
```

When I run `PyAudio().get_device_info_by_index(0)`, I get:

```
{'defaultSampleRate': 16000.0, 'defaultLowOutputLatency': 0.0239375, 'defaultLowInputLatency': 0.0239375, 'maxInputChannels': 1L, 'structVersion': 2L, 'hostApi': 0L, 'index': 0, 'defaultHighOutputLatency': 0.096, 'maxOutputChannels': 2L, 'name': u'Jabra SPEAK 410 USB: Audio (hw:0,0)', 'defaultHighInputLatency': 0.096}
```

^ that (Jabra SPEAK 410 USB: Audio) is my USB mic.

These are the logs PyAudio is spitting out when it is loaded (before the stream is even opened). I've read online, though, that I can ignore most of those errors.

```
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1286:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.USB-Audio.pcm.hdmi.0:CARD=0,AES0=4,AES1=130,AES2=0,AES3=2'
ALSA lib conf.c:4248:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:4727:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM hdmi
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1286:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.USB-Audio.pcm.hdmi.0:CARD=0,AES0=4,AES1=130,AES2=0,AES3=2'
ALSA lib conf.c:4248:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:4727:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM hdmi
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1286:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.USB-Audio.pcm.modem.0:CARD=0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4248:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:4727:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline:CARD=0,DEV=0
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1286:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.USB-Audio.pcm.modem.0:CARD=0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4248:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:4727:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline:CARD=0,DEV=0
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1286:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.USB-Audio.pcm.modem.0:CARD=0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4248:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:4727:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM phoneline
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1286:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.USB-Audio.pcm.modem.0:CARD=0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4248:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:4727:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM phoneline
bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connection refused (111)
bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connection refused (111)
bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connection refused (111)
bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connection refused (111)
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
```

It looks like the stream is collecting data when it's opened, but it is not capture any sound. My mic is turned on, unmuted, and set to capture audio at a level of 86.

I'm thinking it somehow the default device isn't being set properly (with ALSA), because when I do:

`arecord test.wav`

and

`aplay test.wav`

nothing gets recorded.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. It looks like Ubuntu comes with PulseAudio and ALSA. And PulseAudio was hijacking the default device spot.

This is a bit' rigid, but I just removed PulseAudio completely and the issues went away.

`sudo apt-get autoremove pulseaudio`